# JavaFX rotate rectangle about center?

Tags: javafx, rotation, center, rectangles

I'm trying rotate a rectangle around its center. The rotation is being drawn to a canvas using the GraphicsContext ie gc. Here is my draw code.

```
gc.save();    
gc.translate(center.x, center.y);
gc.rotate(this.angle);
gc.strokeRect(0,0, this.width, this.height);   
gc.restore();
```

This moves the rectangle to its center but then it rotates the rectangle around its top left point. I tried subtracting half the length and width of the sides but that just made it fly all over the place. I suck at math maybe someone here who is better can show me what I'm doing wrong.

I also have stored all four points (corners) of the rectangle if that information is needed.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A rotation around a specified point needs to be composed from translate transformations and rotations around the origin as follows:

1. Use translation to move the center of the rotation to the origin.
2. rotate around the origin
3. **use inverse translation to the first translation**

The third part is missing from your code.

**Example**

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
    double x = 50;
    double y = 100;
    double width = 100;
    double height = 200;

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    double rotationCenterX = (x + width) / 2;
    double rotationCenterY = (y + height) / 2;

    gc.save();
    gc.translate(rotationCenterX, rotationCenterY);
    gc.rotate(45);
    gc.translate(-rotationCenterX, -rotationCenterY);

    gc.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    gc.restore();

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(canvas));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

You could also simply use a `Rotate` with a specified pivot to achieve the desired effect:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);
    double x = 50;
    double y = 100;
    double width = 100;
    double height = 200;

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    double rotationCenterX = (x + width) / 2;
    double rotationCenterY = (y + height) / 2;

    gc.save();
    gc.transform(new Affine(new Rotate(45, rotationCenterX, rotationCenterY)));
    gc.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    gc.restore();

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(canvas));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: gc.transform(new Affine(new Rotate(45, rotationCenterX, rotationCenterY))); This solved everything.

Answer (score 4):

It's just so simple, like below.

```
Rectangle rect = new Reactangle(20, 20, 100, 50);
rect.setRotate(30); //rotate the rectangle around its center by 30 degrees.
```

Comment: Please, make sure your answers contains only the information needed to solve the question.

Comment: Your code does not answer the original question. Your code uses the scene graph but the question was about the Canvas.